# Joomla - How to install custom logger class

Tags: class, logging, joomla

To meet my needs, I have created a custom logger class which extends JLogLoggerFormattedtext.
The file is located in the /libraries/joomla/log/logger directory.
This way I can use it like any other logger class and it works fine :

```
JLog::addLogger(
    array(
        'logger' => 'formattedtextsmt',
        'text_file' => 'my_comp_site.log.php',
    ),
    [..]
);
```

But now, I d'like to make it part either from a component I developed or a dedicated library so that it can be installed properly from the admin UI.

How can I do to make my logger class available for addLogger when it is not located in the joomla/log/logger directory ?